# Is $a=b$ when $|a-b|=0$? If so, how can I prove it?

Tags: absolute-value

I was looking at another proof in my book which seemed to use this fact for granted. I am pretty sure it's right, but how could I prove that?

Comment: Which real values $x$ satisfy $|x| = 0$?

Comment: from @Martin R 's comment you even get the direction you were asking for.

Comment: @coreyman 317 You are proving the reverse claim. Can't assume what you need to prove, can you.

Comment: Look at how your book defines the absolute  value function.

Comment: I think you should have tried to do an attempt and shown it with the question. There's a good chance that you would have produced a correct proof by applying the definition of absolute value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of absolute value is

$$
|y|=\begin{cases} y &\text{if }y\geq0\\ -y &\text{if }y\leq0\end{cases}
$$

Therefore, if $|y|=c$, it follows that either $y=c$ or $-y=c$. Can you finish the proof from here?

Comment: I would state that $c\ge0$ because clearly $|y|=-1$ does not have the solution $y=-1$ or $y=1$.

Comment: @PeterForeman Well, technically it's true as I stated it -- the conditional "if $|y|=c$, then..." is always true when the antecedent $|y|=c$ is false (as it must be if $c<0$). But in practice I agree $c\geq0$ is a good condition to check.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish, you can write two equations: if $|a-b|=0$, then either
$$
a - b = 0,
$$
or
$$
b - a = 0,
$$
which means 
$$
a = b,
$$
or
$$
b = a
$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question seems to have a very fundamental answer.

$1. $ If you are aware of [Normed Linear Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) then the answer follows from the definition of norm $|\cdot|$ of $\Bbb R$.

$2.$ If you do not like the answer $1.$ then recall that $|x|=\begin{cases} x,\text{ if $x\ge0$}\\ -x,\text{ if $x< 0$}\end {cases}$

Here given that $|a-b|=0\implies a-b=0\text{ or }b-a=0$ in both case $a=b$.